# WCF Data Service with EF complex type

Tags: entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

I'm just playing with EF5 and Data Services. Decided to test exposing SP. Mapped it to FirmInfo complex type. Running in this stupid error. Cannot seem to figure it out.

I have this complex type .tt template created for me

```
public partial class FirmInfo
{
    public int FirmID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I added this to expose it to MyDataService.svc.cs class:

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<FirmInfo> pSPTest(int id)
{
    return CurrentDataSource.pSPTest(id).AsQueryable();
}
```

I can see it in browser as such:

```
- <pSPTest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
- <element m:type="DB.FirmInfo">
    <FirmID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</FirmID> 
    <Name>Firm Name</Name> 
  </element>
  </pSPTest>
```

but when consuming by c# client app I keep getting this error:
The property 'element' does not exist on type 'Client.ServiceReference.FirmInfo'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How are you consuming the result with the C# client app? If you're using the WCF Data Services client, you should be calling `Execute<T>()` on the `DataServiceContext`.

For guidance on how to use the WC Data Services client to call service operations, check out this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230677.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm using context.Execute<FirmInfo> but after some additional research it came to my attention that OData client library doesn’t support complex types. Even the latest one 5.3.0.0 gives me the following error: Cannot materialize a collection of a primitives or complex without the type 'Client.ServiceReference.FirmInfo' being a collection.<br/>

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that WCF Data Service doesn't return complex type in atom format henece client code cannot consume it correctly.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I was able to get it to work when I change Execute method's param singleResult to false as such: List<FirmInfo> FirmsInfo = context.Execute<FirmInfo>(new Uri("/pSPTest", UriKind.Relative), "GET", false).ToList();

Comment: Roman, answer you question yourself. because you are correct. I had the same issue at the exact same time as you. And it worked. The only thing I had to also do is download the newest version of Microsoft.Data.OData

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this by stating the result of the operation as the collection type that you expect, like this.

```
var query = context.CreateQuery<ObservableCollection<wsAccountView.organisation>>("GetOrganisationsByUserName").AddQueryOption("UserName", @"'SFN\AO'");
var Organisations = query.ToList();
```